# How to parse a string to get array of #tags out of the string?

Tags: java, arrays, string, parsing

so I have this string like
`"#tag1 #tag2    #tag3 not_tag1 not_tag2  #tag4"` (the space between tag2 and tag4 is to indicate there can be many spaces). From this string I want to parse just a tag1, tag2 and so on. They are similar to #tags we see on LinkedIn or any other social media. Is there any easy way to do this using regex or any other function in Java. Or should I do it hard way(i.e. using loops and conditions).

Tag format should be "#" (to indicate tag is starting) and space " "(to indicate end of tag). In between there can be character or numbers but start should be a character only.

example,
input : `"#tag1 #tag2    #tag3 not_tag1 not_tag2 #12tag  #tag4"`
output : `["tag1", "tag2", "tag3", "tag4"]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

split by regex: "#\w+"

EDIT: this is the correct regex, but split is not the right method.

same solution as javadev suggested, but use instead:

```
String input = "#tag1 #tag2    #tag3 not_tag1 not_tag2 #12tag  #tag4";
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("#\\w+").matcher(input);
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(0));
}
```

output with # as expected.

Comment: If you didn't test, aren't sure enough, and just guessing, please don't post it as an answer.

Comment: It is working but #12tag, is also gets selected. I dont know much about regex so sorry for that.

Comment: ah, the requirements changed after i posted my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like:

```
public static void main(String[] args ) {
    String input = "#tag1 #tag2    #tag3 not_tag1 not_tag2 #12tag  #tag4";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("#([A-z][A-z0-9]*) *");

    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
    }
}
```

worked for me :)

Output:
tag1
tag2
tag3
tag4